# Custom Payment Method Not Appearing On Checkout Page (Magento 2.2.x)

Tags: magento2, payment

I am making a Payment Method in Magento 2. Payment method is appearing in Backend but its not getting rendered on checkout page. Here is the file structure i made.

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/registration.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <groups>
        <group id="offline">
            <label>Offline Payment Methods</label>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <methods>
        <method name="sanalpos">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
    </methods>
</payment>
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <sanalpos>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Inspired\Sanalpos\Model\Sanalpos</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Sanal POS</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>Offline</group>
            </sanalpos>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Inspired_Sanalpos" setup_version="1.1"/>
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        <module name="Magento_Payment"/>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        <module name="Magento_Directory" />
        <module name="Magento_Config" />
    </sequence>
</config>
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/etc/payment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <groups>
        <group id="offline">
            <label>Offline Payment Methods</label>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <methods>
        <method name="sanalpos">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
    </methods>
</payment>
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="methodCodes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sanalpos" xsi:type="const">Inspired\Sanalpos\Model\Sanalpos::METHOD_CODE</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="sanalpos" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Sanalpos Payment Gateway</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="api_key" translate="label" type="obscure" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>API Secret Key</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
                    <comment>Test/Live Secret Key</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="min_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                    <comment>$1 is the minimum amount allowed by Stripe Payment</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="max_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
                    <comment>If customer tries to checkout with basket value greater than the maximum allowed they will be prevented from completing the order.</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sanalpos" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Inspired_Sanalpos/js/view/payment/sanalpos</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sanalpos" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/sanalpos.js

```
    define(
        [
            'uiComponent',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
        ],
        function (
            Component,
            rendererList
        ) {
            'use strict';
            rendererList.push(
                {
                    type: 'sanalpos',
                    component: 'Inspired_Sanalpos/js/view/payment/method-renderer/sanalpos'
                }
            );
            /** Add view logic here if needed */
            return Component.extend({});
        }
    );
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/sanalpos.js

```
    define(
    [
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator'
    ],
    function (Component, $) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Inspired_Sanalpos/payment/sanalpos'
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'sanalpos';
            },

            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },

            validate: function() {
                var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
                return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
            }
        });
    }
);
```

> app/code/Inspired/Sanalpos/view/frontend/web/template/payment/sanalpos.html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>

        <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-form'}">
            <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
        </form>

        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="text: $t('Place Order')"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure where i am making the mistake. Also do you guys know how to debug these things as Magento does not give any clue where is the problem ?

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed :

`Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default` in your sanalpos-method.js file

add this :

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',

        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator'
    ],
```

I guess you have added model but missed your model code here in post : Inspired\Sanalpos\Model\Sanalpos :

```
namespace Inspired\Sanalpos\Model;
/**
 * Pay In Store payment method model
 */
class Sanalpos extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    /**
     * Payment code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'sanalpos';

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isOffline = true;

}
```

Also remove your pub/static/frontend , var/view_processed/ folders and then deploy static-content.